# Salvar Campo Automatico

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho a seguinte situação.

No Banco, tenho as tabelas Estado, Cidade, com os dados devidamente cadastrados e vinculados.

Na View gostaria de colocar somente um DropDown com a lista de Cidades, mas gostaria de gravar automático o id do Estado no banco.

```
namespace CadastroMVC.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int CidadeId { get; set; }
        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        public string NomeCidade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gravar aonde? Tem isso ai pra colocar na pergunta.

Comment: Traga o estado num campo tipo `hidden`.

Comment: Gostaria de gravar o id do Estado na tabela Cidades, automaticamente, sem precisar selecionar o estado uma vez, que as tabelas ja estão relacionadas no banco.

Comment: Para gravar o estado em um tabela de cidades, tem que selecionar a estado para que o cadastro saiba, isso não se faz automático...!

Answer (score 4):

Você precisar selecionar o `Estado` novamente ao salvar:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Criar(Class1 class1)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                var estado = contexto.Cidades
                                     .Include(c => c.Estado)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c.CidadeId == class1.CidadeId);

                // Verificar aqui se o estado existe, para evitar erros de referência nula.

                class1.EstadoId = estado.EstadoId; // Não é muito correto fazer isso, mas se você faz questão de salvar o EstadoId, tudo bem.
                context.Class1.Add(class1);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                scope.Complete();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Indice");
        }

        // ViewBags aqui
        return View(class1);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi você quer manter o Id do Estado fixo na sua aplicação.

Pensando nisso, basta no seu método `Create` preencher o `EstadoId` com o valor desejado.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Criar(Cidade cidade)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //setando o estado
                cidade.EstadoId = 1;
                context.Cidades.Add(cidade);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return RedirectToAction("Indice");
            }

            await ViewBags();
            return View(cidade);
        }
```